# Why can't I use volatile together with a vector in C++?

Tags: c++, vector, volatile

A short question. I would like to use a volatile vector object in a multi-threaded application.

```
volatile std::vector<T> my_vector; // T is an integer type
```

a call to it's, for example, resize function

```
T P = 8;
sh->u.s.my_vector.resize(P); // P is just like T, an integer
```

gives me a compile-time error: "No matching member function for call to 'resize'".

The problem is, this vector is inside a volatile class that is shared among the threads like this:

```
shared_info_template<T> volatile *sh;
```

So even removing the "volatile" modifier of the vector still produces the error.

**My goal:** I just want to use a resizable array in that shared object on which multiple threads can operate. How to do this if vector is not working?

**Info**: I am using Clang 7 C++ on Linux.

---

**The full code (removed other non related parts):**

kmp.h

```
typedef struct dispatch_shared_info32 {
  ...
  volatile std::vector<kmp_real32> dbl_vector;
} dispatch_shared_info32_t;

typedef struct dispatch_shared_info64 {
  ...
  volatile std::vector<kmp_real64> dbl_vector;
} dispatch_shared_info64_t;
```

kmp_dispatch.h

```
// replaces dispatch_shared_info{32,64} structures and
// dispatch_shared_info{32,64}_t types
template <typename T> struct dispatch_shared_infoXX_template {
  typedef typename traits_t<T>::unsigned_t UT;
  typedef typename traits_t<T>::floating_t DBL;
  ...
  volatile std::vector<DBL> dbl_vector;
  ...
};

// replaces dispatch_shared_info structure and dispatch_shared_info_t type
template <typename T> struct dispatch_shared_info_template {
  typedef typename traits_t<T>::unsigned_t UT;
  union shared_info_tmpl {
    dispatch_shared_infoXX_template<UT> s;
    dispatch_shared_info64_t s64;
  } u;
  ...
};
```

kmp_dispatch.cpp

```
...
dispatch_shared_info_template<T> volatile *sh;
...
sh = reinterpret_cast<dispatch_shared_info_template<T> volatile *>(
        &team->t.t_disp_buffer[my_buffer_index % __kmp_dispatch_num_buffers]);
...
sh->u.s.dbl_vector.resize(P);
```

Comment: `volatile` won't help you to achieve your goal. You should use mutexes / locks and other forms of proper thread synchronization.

Comment: Why would you want that? `volatile` does *NOT* mean "thread safe".

Comment: yes I know, I will guarantee thread safety myself but as I said, even removing the "volatile" gives me compiler error. I think because of the "volatile" modifier of the *sh itself. I am not allowed to remove that.

Comment: Volatile: "Do not optimize me away. My value might change without you, dear compiler, realizing that it does." That's about it. Your problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: P is just an integer, even using a simple number like 6 gives me that error. T is an integer as well.

Comment: You cannot have a (useful) `volatile std::vector<T>`, because none of the member functions of `std::vector<T>` have `volatile` overloads. As far as I'm aware, this is a conscious design decision. (Additionally, as others have mentioned, `volatile` is not a thread synchronization mechanism. It seems you might want an actual concurrent data structure, which the standard library at this time does not have, IIRC.)

Comment: So I can't use a vector in my position now? Because even removing that "volatile" from the vector everywhere still gives me compiler error. I can't remove the volatile from the sh* though (it's not my decision haha).

Comment: Because you `volatile` qualify the object pointed by `sh`, it's members are `volatile`, in exactly the same way that `const` applies to members of a `const` qualified object. Talk to the person who decided to add all this `volatile`, they seem to have very incorrect ideas about what it does. Perhaps you want a `std::atomic<dispatch_shared_info_template<T> *>`

Comment: Additional worrisome thoughts: the union in `dispatch_shared_info_template` looks like its only purpose is type-punning between unrelated types, and the `reinterpret_cast` is very suspicious

Comment: Java ruined what volatile means... it has nothing to do with thread-safety. If I had a penny for every java dev I see with this mistake...